# VB.NET : Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timer, windows-services

I've encounter this error when using multi-threading. I'm new with it, in my windows application this code works. But I transfer it to windows services I've received "Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart." I'm using System.Timers.Timer instead of System.Windows.Forms.Timer as recommended when creating it in Windows services. This windows services will export some XML file from database, so I need a timer. So time to time, it will check if there's a new products or customer in the database which reads the function below. By default, I've hard coded the time to 1min for testing. Also, I've created a boolean variable if the function is not finish yet. It will not override.

Here's my code :

```
Dim oIsproc_BP As Boolean
Dim oIsproc_ItemMaster1 As Boolean
Dim thrd As Thread

Protected Overrides Sub onstart(ByVal args() As String)

     tmr.Interval = 1000
     AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf tmr_Elapsed
     tmr.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub tmr_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmr.Elapsed

     oIsproc_BP = False 
     oIsproc_ItemMaster1 = False 

     tSecItemMaster.Interval = 60000'oInterval(0)
     AddHandler tSecItemMaster.Elapsed, AddressOf tSecItemMaster_Elapsed
     tSecItemMaster.Start()

     tSecCustomer.Interval = 60000'oInterval(2)
     AddHandler tSecCustomer.Elapsed, AddressOf tSecCustomer_Elapsed
     tSecCustomer.Start()

     tmr.Stop() 
End Sub


Private Sub tSecItemMaster_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tSecItemMaster.Elapsed
  If Not oIsproc_ItemMaster1 Then
      oIsproc_ItemMaster1 = True
      thrd = New Thread(DirectCast(Function() oItemMaster(), ThreadStart))
      thrd.Start()
  End If
  Return
End Sub



Private Sub tSecCustomer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tSecCustomer.Elapsed
  If Not oIsproc_BP Then
      oIsproc_BP = True
      thrd = New Thread(DirectCast(Sub() oBPartners(, "C"), ThreadStart))
      thrd.Start()
  End If
  Return
End Sub
```

And for my function :

```
Private Function oItemMaster(Optional ByVal FirstLoad As Boolean = False, Optional oType As Integer = 1)
     ''My code here

     oIsproc_ItemMaster1 = False

End Function

Private Sub oBPartners(Optional ByVal FirstLoad As Boolean = False, Optional CardType As String = "C")
    ''My code here

     oIsproc_BP = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race - you're using a *single* variable (`thrd`) to hold one of two instances of a `Thread` that you might create. Consider both timers firing at the same time, and the threads that service the timers being interleaved as follows:

```
Timer 1 (tSecItemMaster_Elapsed)    Timer 2 (tSecCustomer_Elapsed)

If Not oIsproc_ItemMaster1 Then
    oIsproc_ItemMaster1 = True
                                    If Not oIsproc_BP Then
                                        oIsproc_BP = True
                                        thrd = New Thread(...)
    thrd = New Thread(...)
    thrd.Start()
End If
Return
                                        thrd.Start()
                                    End If
                                    Return
```

And that's why you get the error message - both timers are trying to start the *single* `Thread` object that was created inside `tSecItemMaster_Elapsed`, and the `Thread` created inside of `tSecCustomer_Elapsed` is never started. Other inter-leavings will introduce similar issues.

A quick  fix would be to create a separate field for storing each thread. I think you may still have a couple of race conditions but they're not leaping out at me at the moment.